# Change length of already persisting column in Hybris?

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud

I am trying to change the length of Description attribute in AbstractRuleEngineRule (visible in promotion rule widget in backoffice)

Since, the column is already persisted in database and we cannot initialize the system, i found a workaround for this by altering the table during update system.

```
@SystemSetup(extension = "ezibuypromotionengine")

public class CoreSystemSetup extends AbstractSystemSetup{

    private static final Logger LOG = Logger.getLogger(CoreSystemSetup.class);

    /**
     * This method will be called during the system update.
     */
    @SystemSetup(type = Type.PROJECT, process = Process.UPDATE)
    public void updateColumnsSize(final SystemSetupContext context)
    {
        Connection conn = null;
        PreparedStatement pstmt = null;
        try
        {
            conn = Registry.getCurrentTenant().getDataSource().getConnection();
            pstmt = conn.prepareStatement("alter table AbstractRuleEngineRule alter column description varchar(500)");
            pstmt.execute();
        }
        catch (final SQLException e)
        {
            LOG.error("Unable to alter database column - " + e);
        }
        finally
        {
            Utilities.tryToCloseJDBC(conn, pstmt, null);
        }
    }
}
```

But i am getting an error

`ERROR [hybrisHTTP26] [CoreSystemSetup] Unable to alter database column - java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: user lacks privilege or object not found: PUBLIC.ABSTRACTRULEENGINERULE`

Answer (score 2):

AbstractRuleEngineRule is the type, not the tablename.  You need to look at the deployment to see what the tablename is. E.g. `<deployment table="EngineRules" ....`

Comment: i made the change but still getting 

`ERROR [hybrisHTTP11] [CoreSystemSetup] Unable to alter database column - java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: user lacks privilege or object not found: DESCRIPTION`

But we do have <attribute qualifier="description"> for AbstractRuleEngineRule

Comment: I believe that you should try with"P_DESCRIPTION"

Comment: If you use the FlexibleSearch Console in the HAC, you can see what columns exist in what tables.  Start with the FlexibleSearch syntax, e.g. select * from {AbstractRuleEngineRule} ... the output will show you the column names & for simple queries you will see the translation to actual SQL in the second tab